# Vite React Project Hosting Problems

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cpanel, vite

So here you go sir, I have a react vite project, i want to deploy it to a sharedhost cpanel? Because in the build, you can only display the homepage, other pages cannot be displayed. how to solve this

thanks.

edit the .htaccess but still not solve the problem